# MYSQL how to select this between 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables.

Table 'posts'

```
post_id    post_content    post_topic
1          "Test"          1
2          "How are you"   1
3          "Hey"           1
4          "What"          2
```

Table 'topics'

```
topic_id    topic_name    topic_forum
1           "Test 1"      1
2           "Test 2"      2
```

Table 'forums'

```
forum_id    forum_name
1           "Food"
2           "Game"
```

For example I want to select all records from **posts** where **topic_forum** is 1

So in this case I supposed to use JOIN?
Can someone explain me how to? Thanks.

Comment: Whas do you means by "post_topic -> topic_forum = 1"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will select all records from Posts where forum_name = 'Food'.

Select P.* from posts P ,topics  T,forums F where F.forum_id =T.topic_forum and T.topic_id=P.post_topic and F.forum_id ='1'

Answer (score 2):

You Need to use Join Query, something  like below code,

```html
SELECT p.*,t.*,f.forum_id 
FROM posts p 
    LEFT JOIN topics t ON p.post_topic=t.topic_id 
    LEFT JOIN forums f on t.topic_forum=f.forum_id 
WHERE t.topic_forum=1
```

Comment: output result should be fine but 2nd left join to `forums` table is not required.

Answer (score 0):

This will list all posts where topic_forum is 1.

```
select * from posts p 
left join topics t 
    on t.topic_id = p.post_topic
where t.topic_forum = 1
```

To list all posts where forum_name = 'Food'

```
select * from posts p 
left join topics t 
    on t.topic_id = p.post_topic
left join forums f
    on f.forum_id = t.topic_forum
where f.forum_name = 'Food'
```